# Not able to run Intern test with non amd code

Tags: javascript, dojo, intern

I am trying to create and run intern test cases for our non AMD javascript, but have not been able to test it.

I have a javascript file called as DBoard.js which has initial lines as

DBoard.js

```
dojo.provide("search.DBoard");
dojo.require("search.SContainer");
....
...
```

I want to test the above file for which I have written the intern test case as

```
define([
        "intern!tdd",
    "intern/chai!assert"

       ],

       function (tdd, assert) {

    with(assert) {

        tdd.suite("test search.DBoard", function() {

            tdd.test("test search.DBoard", function() {

                 var dboard = new search.DBoard();
                 // assert statements

            });
        });
    }
});
```

The error which it gives me everytime is that its not able to find search.Dboard.
I dont know how and where we can provide this dependency. I tried using intern!order but even that did not seem to work.

Can anyone please help me in writing this piece of code for testing non AMD code?

Comment: Hmm. You can require dependencies that are not AMD too. So you should be able to add `"search/DBoard.js"` after `"intern/chai!assert"`. The `.js` indicates that it's not an AMD module. I don't actually know how that will work with the `dojo.require` calls inside DBoard though.

Answer (score 0):

In order to load legacy Dojo modules, if you are using Dojo 1.6- you will need to load `[ 'intern/order!path/to/dojo.js', 'intern/order!path/to/DBoard.js' ]` as dependencies. If you are using Dojo 1.7+ you will need to set `useLoader: { 'host-browser': 'path/to/dojo.js' }` and then load `[ 'path/to/DBoard' ]` as a dependency. More information about `useLoader` can be found in the [documentation on using alternative loaders](https://github.com/theintern/intern/wiki/Using-Intern-with-Alternative-AMD-Loaders-%28like-RequireJS%29).